# Элементы выше главной диагонали прямоугольной матрицы

Tags: c, алгоритм, матрицы

Мы все знаем, как найти элементы выше главной диагонали в квадратной матрице. А что если матрица не квадратная, а просто прямоугольная и как найти в ней все элементы выше главной диагонали? Обычным `if (i <= j)` не обойдешься.

Допустим есть такой код, который делает все элементы выше диагонали 0, остальные - рандомные:

```
int n = 10;
int m = 16;

int** arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*m);

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
}

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = rand() % 9 + 1;

        if (i <= j) //Какое-то корректное условие вместо данного
        {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
        }

        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

Как правильно решить такую задачу?

Comment: Главной диагональю матрицы является диагональ, которая начинается в верхнем левом углу матрицы и изменяется вниз и вправо, пока не будет достигнут правый или нижний край матрицы. 
То есть у вас будет при первом цикле i=0, j = 0, при втором цикле i = 1, j = 1 и т.д.  идти диагональ, до тех пор пока i или j не закончиться

Comment: @Владислав Что для Вас является определением главной диагонали (прямоугольной) матрицы?

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский, Вы правы, но я имел в виду диагональ, которая начинается в точке [0][0] и заканчивается в [m-1][n-1], причем m !=n, диагональ не касается какой-то точки стороны, пока i или j не закончиться, а касается именно точки пересечения сторон (угол), то есть в данном случае элементы диагонали не arr[k][k], а совсем другое, что я и хочу узнать.

Comment: @Igor Я скорее всего не правильно трактую определение главная диагональ. В данном случае, главная диагональ - прямая соединяющая точки [0][0] и [m-1][n-1]

Comment: ну так в том и дело. К примеру  у вас матрица  i = 3 j = 5.  То диагональ будет  [0,0], [1,1], [2,2]. И допустим элемент [2, 3] он уже будет выше главной диоганали

Comment: @Владислав: Это что за "диагональ" такая? Как она проходит при m != n? Что такое "прямая" в матрице?

Comment: @Владислав конкретизируйте вопрос, т.е.начните с [определения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C) главной диагонали прямоугольной матрицы.

Comment: Возможно надо подойти немного с другой стороны и поискать в сети графические программы (примитивы), которые заливают треугольники на физическом уровне.

Comment: Такая "диагональ" будет рисоваться алгоритмом растеризации отрезков, типа Брезенхэма. Но растеризовать наклонный отрезок можно разными способами, т.е. однозначности тут не будет, пока не будет оговорен четкий алгоритм проведения такой диагонали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если понимать искомую разделительную линию здесь, как диагональ прямоугольника, то можно предложить следующий подход:

```
 if (i * n < j * m) 
    arr[i][j] = 2;  //выше диагонали
 else if (i * n == j * m)
     arr[i][j] = 1; //точно на диагонали, таких элементов будет всего НОД(n,m) 
 else
     arr[i][j] = 0; //ниже диагонали
```

для 6x6:

```
1 2 2 2 2 2
0 1 2 2 2 2
0 0 1 2 2 2
0 0 0 1 2 2
0 0 0 0 1 2
0 0 0 0 0 1
```

для 6x9:

```
1 2 2 2 2 2
0 2 2 2 2 2
0 0 2 2 2 2
0 0 1 2 2 2
0 0 0 2 2 2
0 0 0 0 2 2
0 0 0 0 1 2
0 0 0 0 0 2
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

следуя определению главной диагонали которая была дана в комментариях - следующий код напечатает все элементы стоящие выше главной диагонали (кроме самих элементов этой диагонали)

```
constexpr size_t n = 5, m = 4;
int mat[n][m] = 
{
    {1,  2,  3,  4},
    {5,  6,  7,  8},
    {9,  10, 11, 12},
    {10, 11, 12, 13},
    {14, 15, 16, 17}
};

for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = i + 1; j < m; j++)
    {
        cout << mat[i][j] << ' ';
    }

    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: "следуя определению главной диагонали которая была дана в комментариях" - там их несколько. В ответе, какому из них следовали?